# post reguest '422 Unprocessable Entity' with fast api

Tags: python, python-requests, request, fastapi

I have a fast api application, where I want to have a post request.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI


class Data(BaseModel):
    num: str

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/set/")
def set_param(data: Data):
    return data
```

When I send request from another file:

```
import requests,json

req = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/set/',data={'num':'1'}).json()
```

I have an error:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:54236 - "POST /set/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

I don;t know what should I change to eliminate this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not sending a valid **JSON**.

You should use `json` instead of `data`.

```py
json={"num":"1"}
```

Use it like this

```py
req = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/set/',json={'num':'1'}).json()
```

Or you can use `json.dumps()`

```py
req = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/set/', json.dumps(data={'num':'1'})).json()
```

Comment: I think the json.dumps option should be: req = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/set/', data=json.dumps({'num':'1'})).json()
However in my case this didn't work while using the json parameter did.